# CSS not working for reponsive website

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my site responsive but am having trouble getting the triple line menu to show up when the display is small. Here is my css and html coding:

CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {

#button .em:first-child { 
display:block;
}  
#button .em:nth-child(2) { 
display:block;
}
#button .em:nth-child(3) { 
display:block;
}
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('.#button').show();
});

}

#button .em:nth-child(3) { 
display:none;
}

#button{

padding:10px;
position:fixed;
right:0;
top:0;
height: 40px;  
border: 1px solid transparent;
background:#fff;
}

#button .em{  
background-color: #fff;
display:block;
margin-top:0;
width: 22px;
height: 4px;
} 

#button .em + li.em{  
margin-top: 2px;
}
```

and here is the HTML snippet:

```
<ul>
    <button id="button" type="button" style="display:none">
      <span class="em"><li></li></span>
      <span class="em"><li></li></span>
      <span class="em"><li></li></span>
    </button>
</ul>
```

I know I'm doing it wrong but any help would be really appreciated..

Comment: What's the problem? Learn to create a [mcve].

Comment: Your HTML code makes no sense: only `li` elements can be direct children of `ul` (and only `ul` - or `ol` - can be direct parent of `li`). Browsers are trying to fix this as much as they can and that's part of the problem (or another consequence of that highly invali HTML code). So how to code a burger menu? Button OK, 3 span inside OK. Should also have a text visually hidden but that's a bit advanced

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting this from the css and add it as a javascript code on the html page:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {$('.#button').show();});
```

And modifies the css code for something like style:

```
 .em{  
    background-color: #fff;
    display:block;
    margin-top:0;
    width: 22px;
    height: 4px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First mistake is that, you have written javascript/jquery code in between css code.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('.#button').show();
});
```

if you write this jquery separate, there will be javascript error because you have used '.' and '#' both to access button. You need to remove '.' from this code: $('.#button').show(); 
and it should be like : $('#button').show();

Comment: I can only help if you can explain me what you actually need.  I think your css is not good.

Comment: I have a website which when I view on my PC (fullscreen) it shows a primary (Home / About / Contact) navigation. What I wanted was when I view the website on a smaller device (ie mobile phone), was just there to be a triple line menu button instead of the primary navigation I know the CSS is bad. Would you know how to write it proper?

Comment: can you send me complete code to my email address: pawan.developers@gmail.com ? I'll check and guide you.

Comment: Sent you an email.

Comment: I send you code back. you was used wrong bootstrap css and navigation structure as well.